# Building a Python platform wheel for a Raspberry Pi 3 on a MacBook

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I have a `python2` package that contains Rust extensions.

These extensions are cross-compiled for armv7 on my laptop, and are output in `.dylib` files that are then added to the Python package.

The package is built by issueing the command : 
`python setup.py bdist_wheel --plat-name linux-armv7l`

The issue is that this produces the following wheel in the `dist` folder : 
`<mypackage>-0.1.17-cp27-cp27m-linux_armv7l.whl`

The produced wheel is badly named and will not install on a Raspberry Pi.

However, when I rename the wheel to : 
`<mypackage>-0.1.17-cp27-cp27mu-linux_armv7l.whl`

The wheel can now be installed on my Raspberry.

How can I get the `python setup.py bdist_wheel` to output a wheel with the correct tag for my built distribution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cpXXm` and `cpXXmu` specify whether the target python implementation has wide unicode support or not (python was compiled with `--enable-unicode=ucs4` or not). You can check that with

```python
$ python -c "import sys; print('ucs2' if sys.maxunicode == 65535 else 'ucs4')"
```

If it prints `ucs2`, then wheels built with the python installation will produce `cp27m` wheels, otherwise to produce `cp27mu` wheels it should print `ucs4`.

The system python on MacOS does not have wide unicode support, so you will need another installation of python that has one. Either

- install the brewed `python2`:

  ```
  $ brew install python
  ```
- or download and install the latest official `pkg`-installer of python 2.7.15 from [Python.org](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.15/python-2.7.15-macosx10.9.pkg)
- or compile one yourself from source:

  ```
  $ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.15/Python-2.7.15.tgz
  $ tar xvf Python-2.7.15.tgz
  $ cd Python-2.7.15
  $ ./configure --enable-unicode=ucs4
  $ make
  $ make install
  ```

  Note the `--enable-unicode=ucs4` or python will be compiled without wide unicode support.

When building the wheel now, be sure to use the correct executable (not the system's `/usr/bin/python`).

You can read more about wide unicode in [PEP 261](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0261/).

Comment: Glad I could help!